# Añadir nueva pagina con itext7

Tags: c#, itext

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en el cual tengo que sacar una seria de reportes mensuales y para ello estoy usando Itext7.

En la primera página tengo una tabla la cual puede aumentar o disminuir de tamaño según una variable de tipo List<>, pero después de esta tabla quería añadir una página nueva para inserta otra tabla que va en horizontal.

Lo que no se es como añadir esa página nueva, vi por aquí que esta la propiedad Document.NewPage() pero a mi no me sale en mi código, en ese caso como podría añadir la nueva página.

Ademas en caso de añadirla, que propiedad debería de usar para indicar que la pagina es en horizontal.

Gracias.

Comment: Mira esto a ver si te ayuda: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40860358/579895